# how to save has_many checkboxes association in rails in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, controller, has-many

I have the following models:

1) Shift.

2) Employee.

The relation between them is as follows:

shift has_many employees.
and employee belongs_to to a shift.

I want to have a link which leads to a page that has all the shifts as a dropdown and below that I want to have all the employees with checkboxes.

I want to select a shift from the shift dropdown and I want to select all the employees that belong to that shift by using checkboxes in order to assign that shift to the selected employees when i click on the submit button.

How can I implement this in Rails?

Comment: this will be many to many relation and you can use HABTM

Comment: You can first fire a ajax request on selection of an option in **Select Shifts** dropdown, then based on the ID passed find the shift like: `@shift = Shift.where(:id => params[:shift_id]).first`, then find **employees** like: `@shift.employees`

Comment: in my case i want to assign only one shift to the employee at any given point of time. and shift has many employees. how to write a form which will  display  dropdown of shifts and how to list all the employees with checkboxes. and when i click on the save button how i can assign the selected shift to the selected employees like in controller  how to to loop the employee records and how to assign the shift to the employees in loop and save ?

Comment: i dont want to do it with ajax. i want have a submit button which makes html request. and in contoller i want to do  shift assignment to the employees by looping employee records and i want to save the employee records in loop.